# Move images over in HTML after % shrinking?

Tags: css, html, notepad++

I am trying to create a horizontal taskbar. I wanted to use custom images and have them shrunk down to fit. I created a class for this that shrinks the image in the unordered list, but it makes the images have this huge gap. How do I shrink and then force the list images to move next to eachother with a small gap in between?

example image: [image]

list:

```
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="link1.html">
                <img src="images/homepagebutton.png" class="taskbarimages">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="link2.html">
                    <img src="images/historybutton.png" class="taskbarimages">
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url("repeatbg.gif");
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

.taskbarimages {
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
}

#title {
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
.toppage {
    margin-left: 30%;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're also setting their width to 30% (that's 30% of the window).
Set only height 30%, that's enought to shrink em and should automatically set their width accordingly. (if not try adding width: auto; or height in pixels).

```
.taskbarimages {
    height: 30%;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Alternatively, to shrink things down you can also use scale.

```
transform: scale(.3);
-webkit-transform: scale(.3);
```

Comment: nope, it just makes them huge again. I needed the 30% to shrink them down

Comment: Set height to pixels then and you're good, like height: 30px; for instance.

Comment: last question, probably pretty simple. How do I prevent it from moving the list on top a second line if I change the page size? I want the whole bar to shrink, not go to another line. the width % fixed it,  but now that it only works with px it's all messed up with that aspect.

Comment: For responsivness you need to create media queries in your css file for various screen sizes, so that you can control the size (height in this case) of those images based on the screen size, i usually use: @media (max-width: 991.98px){ //set size for tablet here } , and (max-width: 767.98px){ //set size for mobile here }. In alternative you can use height: 5vw; (vw instead of pixels stands for view width, so you basically give them a height based on current window width, but it has not much control. Don't forget to choose my answer as the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Put each of the images in a div and set the margins to 0 and the padding to a desired amount should work or just use css translate to manually move them

Comment: Like, just the singular margin tag or all of the margin-left, margin-right, ect?

Comment: you can selectively do margin right in the left div and margin left in the right div, but just doing margin in general oughta work. Just for future reference to have an easier to manage site, id check out using css flex-box or css grid

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. They don't move at all. I made a class called taskbarmargins and set the margins to 0 and padding to 4 and nothing changed.

Comment: if you do style="transform:translate(x,y);" in the img tag, that should work, but make sure you use the appropraite x and y values

Comment: doesn't that not work if you shrink down the web page though?

Comment: its not the most responsive thing ever, yes, but thats why i suggested using flexbox or css grid, they make it easier to have a responsive website

Comment: this is for a project... I can't do that.